# C# .Net framework versioning

Tags: c#, .net

What can be the issues if I build a solution where all the projets are under targetFrameworkVersion=2.0 but one with targetFrameworkVersion=3.5 and

1. None of the 3.5 features are used
2. Some of the 3.5 features are used but the classes calling the 3.5 code are never instanciated
3. Some of the 3.5 features are used in some classes, the classes are instanciated but the code in 3.5 never called
4. the 3.5 code is called

Comment: Are you using any build tool ? or Visual Studio ?

Comment: Visual studio or buil in a teamsystem server depending on the project

Comment: What features are there of .NET 3.5 that you can use without instantiating classes? Or are you talking about C# 3.0?

Comment: I mean by "feature" a lambda expression for eg. I mean by "feature used but class not nistancated" that I have a class with some lambda expressions in the code but the class is never instanciated

Comment: You are confusing C# 3.0 with .NET 3.5. Lambda expressions are a C# 3.0 feature that do not depend on .NET 3.5.

Comment: @John Saunders - Although you're technically correct (the best kind of correct), I'm pretty sure there are some cases where Lambda syntax will compile to use an `Action<>` delegate, which will require .NET 3.5. I may be wrong about that though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "features".  There are compile-time features like the `var` keyword and lambda expressions and there are run-time features like LINQ or WCF that require libraries in the .NET 3.x runtime.

I assume you're using Visual Studio 2008, which will handle all the compile-time features.  If all you're using is the compile-time features, then everything will work fine in all cases.  I do this rather often on my current project.

If you're using run-time features then I believe this is how it will shake out:

1. Things will just work.
2. I think this will just work also.
3. It depends on when static functions are JITted and if you have any 3.5 library referencing code in static functions.
4. Probably `MissingMethodException` when a function containing a 3.5 library feature is called.

Rather than worry about all of this, if you're planning on using run-time features, I would simply add a key to the App.config that the 3.5 runtime is required and it'll check on startup and bomb if it isn't present.  Then you don't need to figure out all these permutations and your application will be more stable.

Comment: Ok, I globally figured the same out. My main concern was 2 and 3 whith run-time features. I wondered if there is a check on all the assemblies potentally needed and when.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you're compiling on a machine that obviously has the 3.5 Framework installed.  So all the references in the one DLL will work and compile properly.  But then you're loading (and JITting) that DLL on a machine that may or may not have the 3.x runtime installed.  CLR via C# by Jeffery Richter has a great discussion of when all these activities happen and would be your best bet for getting the exact answers.  IIRC, you'll only run into issues when a function is JITted and functions are JITted when they're first called.

Comment: Ok, so if install the 3.5 framework on all the client machine, 1,2,3,4 will works ?

Comment: Yes, because unless you specify in the App.config that you want the process to only load the .NET 2.0 Framework, the .NET 3.5 Framework will be loaded and all the references to .NET 3.5 functions will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to be aware that what you are targeting is actually **.NET 2.0 SP1**.

How are your projects related? Do you have projects that are built under .NET 2.0 which reference the .NET 3.5 project (or vice versa)?

Comment: I have both. 3.5 references 2.0 and 2.0 references 3.5